# Force deduction of template parameter to reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

The following code does not compile because the compiler deduce a template parameter to be `int` while it would be required to be `int &`. See it on Coliru [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d50215b56b2714a).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class F, class... ArgsType>
void do_something(F f, ArgsType... args)
{
    f(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    int s = 2;
    int i = 1;
    auto add = [](const int a, int& sum) { sum += a; };
    do_something(add, i, s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void do_something(F, ArgsType ...) [with F = main()::<lambda(int, int&)>; ArgsType = {int, int}]':

main.cpp:15:27:   required from here

main.cpp:7:6: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(int, int&)>) (int, int)'

     f(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);

     ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: 'void (*)(int, int&)' <conversion>

main.cpp:7:6: note:   conversion of argument 3 would be ill-formed:

main.cpp:7:6: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'

main.cpp:14:40: note: candidate: 'main()::<lambda(int, int&)>' <near match>

     auto add = [](const int a, int& sum) { sum += a; };

                                        ^

main.cpp:14:40: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:

main.cpp:7:6: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'

     f(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);

     ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Ideally, the third argument of `do_something` should be deduced as `int&`. One way to do this is to explicitly pass the template parameters as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class F, class... ArgsType>
void do_something(F f, ArgsType... args)
{
    f(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    int s = 2;
    int i = 1;
    auto add = [](const int a, int& sum) { sum += a; };
    do_something<decltype(add), const int, int&>(add, i, s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

See it on Coliru [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0abcb205e985615b).

While the solution works, I find it inconvenient, because it forces me to provide *all* template types of `do_something`, which is not optimal especially if, say, I have a more complex example with several parameters, or if I would like to insert the lambda function `add` directly as a parameter of
 `do_something`:

```
do_something([](const int a, int& sum) { sum += a; }, i, s);
```

Is there a more convenient way to force just the third parameter to be deduced as `int &`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
template <class F, class... ArgsType>
void do_something(F f, ArgsType&&... args)
//                            ^^^^ ---------------> perfect forwarding
{
    f(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Understanding the problem

the second parameter (`sum`) of your lambda expression

```
auto add = [](const int a, int& sum) { sum += a; };
```

is an *lvalue reference*.

The parameter pack, `ArgsType` in

```
template <class F, class... ArgsType>
void do_something(F f, ArgsType... args);
```

is deduced to the argument pack `int`, `int` when passing the variables `i` and `s` as arguments, respectively.

Keeping in mind that `std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...` is the same as `static_cast<ArgsType&&>(args)...` (i.e., it is just cast to an *rvalue reference* type), the call to `do_something()` would be equivalent to calling the following function template:

```
template <class F>
void do_something(F f, int a, int b)
{
    f(static_cast<int&&>(a), static_cast<int&&>(b));
}
```

The expression `static_cast<int&&>(b)` is an *rvalue* (an *xvalue*, to be more precise). Since you cannot initialise an lvalue reference (the parameter) with an rvalue (the argument), it results in a compilation error.

---

#### Solution

You can use [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) instead:

```
template <class F, class... ArgsType>
void do_something(F f, ArgsType&&... args);
```

The type of the separate arguments of the argument pack `args` will always be a reference:

- An *lvalue* reference type if an lvalue was passed as an argument.
- An *rvalue* reference type if an rvalue was passed as an argument.

This way, for your function call, the parameter pack `ArgsType` will be deduced to the argument pack `int&`, `int&` which would be equivalent to calling the following function template:

```
template <class F>
void do_something(F f, int& a, int& b)
{
    f(static_cast<int& &&>(a), static_cast<int& &&>(b));
}
```

Since [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) applies to `static_cast<int& &&>(b)`, the expression results in `static_cast<int&>(b)`, which is an lvalue. An lvalue reference type can be initialised with an lvalue.

However, note that the call:

```
do_something(add, i, 7);
                     ^
                     |
                     --- rvalue
```

won't compile now, since an rvalue is being passed to `add` as a second argument. The reasoning is similar to your original error.